# how to get all videos from Youtube API in android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am using [Youtube URL](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%22TaarakMehtakaOoltahChashmah%22&v=2&alt=jsonc)

```
[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%cid%22&v=2&alt=jsonc][1]
```

It give me results but not with order by episode.

So for getting all episodes order by which URL i have to use ?

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can order the results by published date using "orderby" parameter in youtube Data Api.

Check this out:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#orderbysp

Comment: I checked out it but it not give me orderby episodes. I try with all orderby options. Can you please guide me how to get all episodes orderby episodes ?

Comment: using "orederby" parameter you can get the videos in the order of published date. But this might be different from the order that the episodes were telecasted.